# Change Log4J's Threshold dynamically through user input

Tags: java, sockets, logging, log4j

I'm writing a simple console application which sends and receives data to/from a socket via user commands, such as `"send hello"` -> receives `"hello"` from socket. One of the available commands should be logLevel `(ALL|WARN|DEBUG|etc.)`, which enables the user to set the log level of the Log4J logger which I'M using throughout the application.

Right now, I specified two Appenders in my properties file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=./logs/client.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# info and above messages are printed to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

My goal here is to send all log entries from any level to the logfile, but only the ones that match the specified log level currently set by the user to stdout. A sample workflow could look like this:

```
> INFO: current log level is INFO and above.
> send hello
> INFO: sending hello to server
> INFO: receiving "hello" from server
> logLevel WARN
> INFO: log level set to warn
> send hello
> # no info here, but its still sent to the logfile
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My goal here is to send all log entries from any level to the logfile, but only the ones that match the specified log level currently set by the user to stdout.

So essentially you want to change the threshold on the `stdout` appender programmatically.  This is easy enough to do, the wrinkle is that the threshold property is part of the `AppenderSkeleton` abstract class (which `ConsoleAppender` extends) rather than the `Appender` interface itself.

```
((AppenderSkeleton)Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("stdout"))
   .setThreshold(Level.toLevel(levelNameProvidedByUser));
```

If you really do want *all* log messages to go to the file then you should probably configure the root logger level to ALL rather than INFO in your `log4j.properties`, and rely on the threshold to filter stdout.

Answer (score 1):

My requirement is to add specific logs to one of my log file. I have two log files. One for normal case and other I have to add only specific logs. Means I have to make threshold off by default. Once requires I have to make threshold INFO  and add then logs to my log file and then again make threshold OFF.
This is my code of java

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger();
Appender appender = logger.getAppender("logFileName");
((AppenderSkeleton)appender).setThreshold(Level.INFO);
logger.info(myString.toString());
((AppenderSkeleton)appender).setThreshold(Level.OFF);
```

So only myString is log to my logFileName file.